# How can I match an exact string that may be broken up with white-space?

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

I am searching for an exact string that may be broken up by white-space. Is there a regex that can find this? I am using PowerShell/.NET

Example: 
Find 'ABCDEFG'

```
// Should match
ABCDEFG

// Should not match
ABC4DEFG

// Should match
ABCD
EFG

// Should not match
A4BCD
EFG
```

The best solution that I came up with is to read in each character in the string and skip matching on white-spaces. I'm just hoping that there is more simple answer.

Edit: Not sure why this question is getting down-votes. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: Did you try `A\s*B\s*C\s*D\s*E\s*F\s*G`

Comment: The string is dynamic, so I wouldn't be able to use a static solution like that, but I could build the regex like Loren and Briantist mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes the easiest solution is not to do everything in regex. PowerShell example:

```
$myString -replace '\s' -match 'ABCDEFG'
```

For pure regex, you'd want to separate each character with whitespace:

```
A\s*B\s*D\s*E\s*F\s*G\s*
```

Something like this could be generated at runtime in code.

```
$stringToMatch = 'ABCDEFG'
$regex = $stringToMatch -replace '\B', '\s*'

$myString -match $regex
```

Comment: Thanks @briantist. I ended up using the replace example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you best answer would be:

```
/A\s*B\s*C\s*D\s*E\s*F\s*G\s*/
```

Note: You could use a for loop to build this looping over each letter of the string if the string is long.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (tested here: https://regex101.com/r/isXw1f/1)

```
A\s?B\s?C\s?D\s?E\s?F\s?G
```

Regex must be set to match globally

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all whitespaces first with `\s*` and then match whatever you need. Depends on what you intend to do with the match, if the whitespaces are needed then you'll have to find something else.